# View images in Excel that are saved on a shared drive?

Tags: excel, image, vba

I have VBA code that takes an image url and post the image if it exists in a shared drive.  When I try to send the excel file with the images to someone who does not have access to the shared drive, they cannot view the images.  Is there a way around this so I can send to anyone and they can view the image?

Comment: Are the images in the Excel document? Or are they linked from the document?

Comment: I have put in the url (if it exists) and then with VBA, if there is a link, I select the image so I am assuming they're linked?

Comment: I mean, is the image itself in the file? Or is it just linked to the network drive. AFAIK, if you have the image itself in the file, it should be visible by anyone with access to the Excel file, regardless of access to the network.

Answer (score 0):

If someone doesn't have privileges to view the images on the drive, then they can's access the images.  Nevertheless, you can load them all into Excel, and send the Excel file to your colleague(s).

List all the images (in Column A) that you want to send out, and run the script below.

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1

For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName = r.Value Then
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

' Note: you need the file extension, such as ',jpg', or whatever you are using, so you can match on that.
```